# Объединить фреймы, оставить только те записи, которые встречаются во всех фреймах (в определенном столбце)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

Пусть на входе даны несколько DF. Каждый из них содержит список фирм и несколько показателей: Xn, за один конкретный год! второй DF- за другой и т.д.
Например: первый DF за 2015 год

```
  FIRM  x1  x2  x3
0    A   5   6   5
1    B   5   6   8
2    C   9   9   9
3    D   5   6   7
4    E   0   1   3
5    F   2   1   2
```

второй DF - 2016 год.

```
  FIRM  x1  x2  x3
0    B   4   5   6
1    D   8   8   5
2    A   1   1   1
3    V   3   3   3
4    N   5   5   5
5    M   9   9   9
```

Необходимо отобрать только те фирмы, которые встречались во всех годах и вывести данные по ним в подобном формате:

```
FIRM    YEAR    x1  x2  x3
A   2015    5   6   5
A   2016    1   1   1
B   2015    5   6   8
B   2016    4   5   6
D   2015    5   6   7
D   2016    8   8   5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
items = [d1.assign(YEAR=2015), d2.assign(YEAR=2016)]

res = (pd.concat(items, ignore_index=True)
         .groupby('FIRM')
         .filter(lambda x: x['YEAR'].nunique()==len(items))
         .sort_values(['FIRM','YEAR']))
```

результат:

```
  FIRM  x1  x2  x3  YEAR
0    A   5   6   5  2015
8    A   1   1   1  2016
1    B   5   6   8  2015
6    B   4   5   6  2016
3    D   5   6   7  2015
7    D   8   8   5  2016
```

Comment: `d1.assign(YEAR=2015)` вот тут наверное `df1` должно быть?

Comment: @Max, я назвал фреймы `d1` и `d2`, чтобы короче было... ;)

Comment: Понял, `assign` для отождествления фрейма с годом?

Comment: @Max, да, для добавления столбца с единственным значением

Comment: А что вот эта строчка означает? `filter(lambda x: x['YEAR'].nunique()==len(items))`

Comment: У pd.concat просто нет таких аргументов в хелпе, вы их просто вызываете, вне этой функции?

Comment: `filter()` используется для фильтрования внутри группы после группировки

Comment: [pd.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) - в help вроде бы все описано, не уверен что понял вопрос...

Comment: В какой момент происходит отсев только тех значений, которые встречались во всех годах?

Comment: @Max, в `filter()`

Comment: Это я понимаю что в этой строке, мой ход рассуждения правильный?
`lambda x`  - это некая переменная для которой : `x['YEAR'].nunique()==len(items))` верно?

Comment: В свою очередь `x` мы берем из столбца YEAR, уникальное значение которых должно совпадать с числом DF ?

Comment: lambda - это неименованная функция. Если хотите понять что будет в переменной `x`, то советую создать небольшой игрушечный DF с дубликатами в столбце `FIRM` и выполнить: `df.groupby('FIRM').apply(lambda x: print(x))`

Comment: Так, я создал. И что дальше происходит после такой группировки?

Comment: @Max, можете задать новый вопрос с соответствующим примером данных (так чтобы было по 1-3 строк для каждой фирмы)?

Comment: И задачу ту же поставить? Я просто пытаюсь вникнуть в код, но не до конца получается(

Comment: Вопросы (много) вы уже сформулируровали в комментариях... ;-) Если правильно понял, вы не понимаете как работает метод `.filter()`... Или у вас другой/другие вопросы?  Вот этот вопрос и задайте. В комментариях невозможно полноценно ответить - ни код, ни результат в комментариях нормально показать нельзя

Comment: Ну да по сути, я понимаю что это должно давать на выходе, но за счет чего, не понимаю. Так стоп, а зачем мне дубликаты в FIRM ?))) задача же изначально ставится на поиск уникальных значений. Изначально вопрос стоял в том, что делает эта строка `filter(lambda x: x['YEAR'].nunique()==len(items))`