# Как работают методы фильтрации нескольких DF

Tags: база-данных, pandas

Есть два исходных DF за 2015 и 2016 годы соответственно:

`FIRM   x1  x2  x3
A   5   6   8
A   6   6   4
A   5   6   4
B   6   6   5
B   6   6   5
C   5   6   4
D   6   4   5`

и

`FIRM   x1  x2  x3
B   5   6   8
C   6   6   4
F   5   6   4
B   6   6   5
B   6   6   5
A   5   6   4
A   6   4   5`
Данная задача продолжает: [Объединить фреймы, оставить только те записи, которые встречаются во всех фреймах (в определенном столбце)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/915815/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0/915823?noredirect=1#comment1509187_915823)
На двух данных примерах необходимо показать как работают различные методы фильтрации с помощью: `filter()`. Конкретно , что делает команда `lambda x: x['YEAR'].nunique()==len(items)`  и как она работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего показать как работает `df.groupby(...).filter(...)` на одном DataFrame.

NOTE: в предыдущем ответе группировка и фильтрация применяется к результату применения функции `pd.concat()`, которая в свою очередь объединяет несколько фреймов в один.

Исходный DF:

```
In [62]: df
Out[62]:
  FIRM  x1  x2  x3
0    A   5   6   8
1    A   6   6   4
2    A   5   6   4
3    B   6   6   5
4    B   6   6   5
5    C   5   6   4
6    D   6   4   5
```

Допустим мы хотим получить данные только для тех фирм, для которых существует 2+ строк:

```
In [63]: df.groupby('FIRM').filter(lambda z: len(z) > 1)
Out[63]:
  FIRM  x1  x2  x3
0    A   5   6   8
1    A   6   6   4
2    A   5   6   4
3    B   6   6   5
4    B   6   6   5
```

[метод `.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) применяет функцию (в нашем случае это "лямбда" функция) к каждой группе (группа является подмножеством DataFrame с такой же структурой как у `df`). Функция в методе `.filter(func)` должна возвращать булевый скаляр (`True` или `False`)

Comment: Когда мы пишем `groupby('FIRM')` , то и `z`  будут столько строки из это столбца `FIRM` ?

Comment: нет `z` - это подмножество `df` с такой же структурой (со всеми столбцами) - в `z` будут данные для одной фирмы. Выпробовали сделать `df.groupby('FIRM').apply(lambda z: print(z))` как я вам раньше советовал - там вроде бы все понятно ...

Comment: Да, я пробовал, он делит будто на кучу разных таблиц по уникальными значениям.

Comment: правильно, так вы напечатаете на экран все группы (одна группа для каждой группы). Первая группа может напечататься дважды - не обращайте на это внимания - это специфика внутренней реализации метода `.apply()`

Comment: И команда далее смотрит каждую из групп и находит вот это условие? `lambda z: len(z) > 1` ?

Comment: Это лямбда функция фильтрации, которая применяется к каждой группе. В данном случае если группа состоит из более чем одной строки, то вся группа остается в результате, иначе выбрасывается